# How to define type for "main" script in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mime-types

I have the following `script` tag on **index.html**:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="scripts/main" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

This will load **scripts/main.js**:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    shim: {
        'lib/angular': { exports: 'angular' },
        'app': ['lib/angular']
    }
    scriptType: 'application/javascript'
});

require(['app'], function () {
   // Some code
});
```

As you can see I am defining `scriptType: 'application/javascript`.

This works for loaded dependencies, but does not work for **main.js** itself.

This is my generated HTML:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="scripts/main" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async-data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="main" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" charset="utf-8" async-data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="lib/angular" src="scripts/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" charset="utf-8" async-data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

As you can note, `scripts/main.js` is being loaded with `type="text/javascript"`.

How can I make it load with `type="application/javascript"` as the rest of the scripts?

Comment: you can define config in your `index.html` instead https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/354

Comment: @llamerr How did that never occur to me? I'd rather have a separate JS file but if that can't be achieved, then this solution is fair enough. Mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: sure thing, seems it's also possible to keep config in separate js file instead of html. the only requirement is to include it before running requirejs. going to check it for sure and will post answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this I'm doing same as you did but moving config.js to a separate file. In that case you need to specify `type` for config by yourself (if you need to have same type for config). The trick is that you need to execute `require()` after your config is ready

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/354#issuecomment-6631063 (2nd variant, but i used `yo requirejs` for test)

index is

```
  <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script src="app/config.js"></script>
  <script>
    // same as data-main
     require(['app/main'], function(){ });
  </script>
```

config is

```
require.config({
  // make components more sensible
  // expose jquery
  paths: {
    "components": "../bower_components",
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery"
  },
  scriptType: 'application/javascript'
});
```

and main file is

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
  $('body').append('jQuery ' + $.fn.jquery + ' loaded!');
});
```

[image]